# Did something change with uTorrent speed capping?

Tags: download, speed, bittorrent, utorrent

I download a lot of Linux torrents for testing systems every time there is a new release. And Linux torrents are always seeded well so seeding is not the issue here. Neither is firewall, I have port forwarding setup properly. I did a glasnost test and my ISP does not throttle my connection. So...

I've tested and verified over the past year that I would get the maximum download speed possible with my connection(2MBps) if I have at least 6kbps upload set.

Lately this is not true. If I have 6kbps upload my download gets capped at ~91kbps. If I have 10kbps upload the max download I get is around 153kbps. And so on. I can clearly see that the download speed increases as I increase the upload speed in steps.

So did something change with uTorrent? I'm using uTorrent 2.0 Beta. Should I go back to the non-beta version?

Can someone confirm that this is happening. I'm going mad trying to analyze the source of this.

You can go to this link and see the image for further explanation as to what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: This isn't happening in the latest version of μTorrent you installed, right? I realize it's been about three years since you asked the question, but it would be great if you could accept the correct answer and/or vote to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

I just found out that this a bug in the current build of uTorrent 2.0 Beta. When uTP is enabled it erroneously throttles the download rate based on the upload rate.

Found this answer by fishing around uTorrent forums and found these 2 links that refer to the same problem.

http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=441281